# How to set the value of a form element in contact.html page, when I click a link using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two pages:

1. the products page, that has the products, and every product has a "Send us a message" link;
2. the contact page, that has a form with four elements: name, email, subject and message;

when i click on the "Send us a message" link in products.html page, i would like that the value of "Subject" element of the form in contact.html, to be the title of the product.

So, if I have a product with the title "BMW 530xd 2009", when I click the link "Send us a message" below it I would like to send me tot the contact.html page and the "Subject" field of the form to be autocompleted with "BMW 530xd 2009".

How I do that with javascipt?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have the field already set with the value, i don't know the technology you are using on server side...

anyway and to answer you question using javascript you can use form's handler **onsubmit** to do the job

```
<form onsubmit="return fillProd(this)" ...
<input name="subject" ....
```

now and again having server side to provide us the value would be nice but the value can be obtained client side from the document DOM either using DOM function or jquery (or something similar)

suppose you have the product title like

```
<div class="prod-title" id="prodtitle">BMW 530xd 2009</div>
```

then we can get the value using jquery

```
$("#prodtitle").html
```

or using DOM

```
document.getElementById("prodtitle").innerHTML
```

example of function using DOM

```
function fillProd(form) {
   form.subject.value=document.getElementById("prodtitle").innerHTML;
   return true;
}
```

note: the return's on form handler and on function (rerturning true) are very important

Answer (score 0):

You could load the contact.html form inside the products.html page using ajax when someone clicks the said link, then you would be able to change values if you handle everything right, because as far as I know you can't change form values from one page to another using client side language.

Another option would be writting the form directly inside the contact.html with a css property of display:none; so when someone clicks a link it changes to display:block; with the value change handled in your javascript.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

make the link of "send message" like this:
contact.html?subject=your_value_here

on contact.html you can retrieve the value like this

```
if(location.search) {
   subject = location.search;
}
```

and to populate the subject (which i missed the first time)

```
document.getElementById("id_of_subject_field").innerHTML = subject;
```

It's not an elegant solution, but it should do the trick.